# How to debug scalatra application in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: debugging, scala, intellij-idea, scalatra

I can't find any documentation or examples of debugging Scalatra apps in IntelliJ Idea. 
Is it possible to run the Scalatra app in debug mode to attach the Idea?

Comment: On the last ScalaDev i've asked one of JetBrains' guys about scalatra support and he told that have plans to add it soon

Comment: Debugging any JVM app, including scalatra should be no different from the way described in the above link. First -- you're starting scalatra with additional options (they're listed in that topic and in IDEA run configurations tab), then you're attaching IDEA debugger [in remote mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-remote.html).

Comment: @om-nom-nom, I don't know how to start the scalatra app in debug mode, and my question clearly states that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First. Go to the IDEA an choose *edit configurations* action:

[image]

On this tab, add new remote configuration:

[image]

Next, [run Scalatra with those options](http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/guides/deployment/standalone.html):

[image]

For example:

```
java 
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005  -jar **-assembly-**.jar
```

Now hit the green debug button of your IDEA and enjoy debugging. There might be another ways to run scalatra (e.g. from sbt jetty-run) but generally all you need is to feed those options to the jvm instance.